# git fork into an independent repository?

Tags: git, github

I created a fork from some other users repository a long time ago. Then I made a lot of changes into my fork and re-wrote a lot of code.

Now I want to turn this fork into a repository on my account, as these two are really different I want to remove the relationship between the two. So that I can have issue tracking for this fork separately etc.

How can I do that ? I have tried looking around but did not find a good example.

Comment: Creating a new repository and pushing into that would do it right?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just add a remote to your new host and start pushing there.

```
git remote add newremote git@whatever.com/newrepo
git push -u newremote master //the -u will set this as the default
```

Clearly the whole commit history from the original repo will still be there.

Then, if you like, you can also remove the reference to the original remote (this does not make any difference, but it is surely cleaner)

```
git remote rm origin //or whatever the original remote is named
```

Comment: This will make 2 remotes, which OP might not want, I got an impression OP wanted to completely divorce the repository from old remote.

Comment: That wouldn't be such a big deal. It would be just a matter of removing the original remote.

Comment: I think I can try this method without any risk of losing my commit history.

Comment: changing the remote won't affect your commit history.

Comment: But in case you have stars on your repositories they will be deleted...

Comment: not work for me

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a crude idea, but I'd just rm -rf .git and git init and git remote add and push.

If you want to keep your commits, reassign your remote URL with:

```
git remote set-url --delete origin your-github-url
git remote set-url --add origin your-github-url
```

Comment: I don't want to lose my commit history, Will just changing the origins be fine ?

Comment: Yes, changing remotes is absolutely safe, by default a git repo has one remote, called origin, so you can either remove and readd it, as Gabriele advised, or update the origin url, as I did.

Comment: That isn't crude, it's the all-out-WWIII nuclear option...